# Governing equations vs Transport equations

Tags: navier-stokes, differential-equations

This is a basic question. But I did not find any explanations for this. How are governing equations, like mass, momentum, energy conservations equations, different from 'Transport equation'?. Is a conservation equation, like energy equation (heat equation), a transport equation for the temperature?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't think this is the correct Stack Exchange site for this question under the current rules, since there is no computation involved. I guess the Physics sister site might be the best fit, and is an extremely friendly community. Two possible answers are "it depends on the writer" and "transport equation is often used only for quantities which can't influence their own velocity."

Comment: Governing equations are the equations that govern a phenomenon or a process; therefore, it is a generic term. Transport equations are a specific type of governing equations that describe how a quantity, for example, the concentration of species, velocity etc., is transported in space and/or time.
Yes, the heat equation which governs the transfer of heat is a transport equation.